# Avoid product type when updating cart count with ajax in shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a script which updates the cart count on my Shopify store using Ajax. This works fine, however I have a particular product type that I don't want including in the count. I've managed to get this to work on a normal page refresh using the code below (found from a forum post), but can't understand how to edit the Ajax script so that the count updates using Ajax but avoiding product type mw_product_option.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance, I'd appreciate it.

```
<a href="/cart" id="cartCount">
{% assign num = 0 %}     
{% for item in cart.items %}            
{% if item.product.type != "mw_product_option" %}       
     {% capture temp %}{{ num | plus: item.quantity }}{% endcapture %} 
{% endif %}
{% assign num = temp %}
{% endfor %}
<span class="CartCount-alt">{{ num }}</span>
```

**Ajax script I'd like to update to avoid counting 'mw_product_option':**

```
// Update cart count and show cart link.
   $.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL, function(cart) {
   if (_config.cartCountSelector && $(_config.cartCountSelector).size()) {
     var value = $(_config.cartCountSelector).html() || '0';
     $(_config.cartCountSelector).html(value.replace(/[0-9]+/,cart.item_count)).removeClass('hidden-count');
   }
```

**Ajax script in full:**

```
Shopify.AjaxifyCart = (function($) {

  // Some configuration options.
  // I have separated what you will never need to change from what
  // you might change.

  var _config = {

// What you might want to change
addToCartBtnLabel:             'Add to cart',
addedToCartBtnLabel:           'Added to cart!',
addingToCartBtnLabel:          'Adding...',
soldOutBtnLabel:               'Sold Out',
howLongTillBtnReturnsToNormal: 1000, // in milliseconds.
cartCountSelector:             '.cart-count, #cart-count a:first, #gocart p a, #cart .checkout em, .item-count, .CartCount, .CartCount-alt',
cartTotalSelector:             '#cart-price',
// 'aboveForm' for top of add to cart form, 
// 'belowForm' for below the add to cart form, and 
// 'nextButton' for next to add to cart button.
feedbackPosition:              'belowForm',

// What you will never need to change
addToCartBtnSelector:          '[type="submit"]',
addToCartFormSelector:         'form[action="/cart/add"]',
shopifyAjaxAddURL:             '/cart/add.js',
shopifyAjaxCartURL:            '/cart.js'
  };

  // We need some feedback when adding an item to the cart.
  // Here it is.  
  var _showFeedback = function(success, html, $addToCartForm) {
$('.ajaxified-cart-feedback').remove();
var feedback = '<p class="ajaxified-cart-feedback ' + success + '">' + html + '</p>';
switch (_config.feedbackPosition) {
  case 'aboveForm':
    $addToCartForm.before(feedback);
    break;
  case 'belowForm':
    $addToCartForm.after(feedback);
    break;
  case 'nextButton':
  default:
    $addToCartForm.find(_config.addToCartBtnSelector).after(feedback);
    break;   
}
// If you use animate.css
// $('.ajaxified-cart-feedback').addClass('animated bounceInDown');
$('.ajaxified-cart-feedback').slideDown();
  };
  var _setText = function($button, label) {
    if ($button.children().length) {
  $button.children().each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) !== '') {
      $(this).text(label);
    }
  });
}
else {
  $button.val(label).text(label);
}
  };
  var _init = function() {   
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      $(_config.addToCartFormSelector).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $addToCartForm = $(this);
    var $addToCartBtn = $addToCartForm.find(_config.addToCartBtnSelector);
    _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addingToCartBtnLabel);
    $addToCartBtn.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
    // Add to cart.
    $.ajax({
      url: _config.shopifyAjaxAddURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      data: $addToCartForm.serialize(),
      success: function(itemData) {
        // Re-enable add to cart button.
        $addToCartBtn.addClass('inverted');
        _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addedToCartBtnLabel);
        _showFeedback('success','<div class="added-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-check large-icon"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Added to your cart! <a href="/cart">View cart</a> or <a href="/collections/all">continue shopping</a>.</div>',$addToCartForm);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled').removeClass('inverted');
          _setText($addToCartBtn,_config.addToCartBtnLabel);
        }, _config.howLongTillBtnReturnsToNormal);
        // Update cart count and show cart link.
        $.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL, function(cart) {
          if (_config.cartCountSelector && $(_config.cartCountSelector).size()) {
            var value = $(_config.cartCountSelector).html() || '0';
            $(_config.cartCountSelector).html(value.replace(/[0-9]+/,cart.item_count)).removeClass('hidden-count');
          }
          if (_config.cartTotalSelector && $(_config.cartTotalSelector).size()) {
            if (typeof Currency !== 'undefined' && typeof Currency.moneyFormats !== 'undefined') {
              var newCurrency = '';
              if ($('[name="currencies"]').size()) {
                newCurrency = $('[name="currencies"]').val();
              }
              else if ($('#currencies span.selected').size()) {
                newCurrency = $('#currencies span.selected').attr('data-currency');
              }
              if (newCurrency) {
                $(_config.cartTotalSelector).html('<span class=money>' + Shopify.formatMoney(Currency.convert(cart.total_price, "{{ shop.currency }}", newCurrency), Currency.money_format[newCurrency]) + '</span>');
              } 
              else {
                $(_config.cartTotalSelector).html(Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, "{{ shop.money_format | remove: "'" | remove: '"' }}"));
              }
            }
            else {
              $(_config.cartTotalSelector).html(Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, "{{ shop.money_format | remove: "'" | remove: '"' }}"));
            }
          };
        });        
      }, 
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        var response = eval('(' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ')');
        response = response.description;
        if (response.slice(0,4) === 'All ') {
          _showFeedback('error', response.replace('All 1 ', 'All '), $addToCartForm);
          $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false);
          _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.soldOutBtnLabel);
          $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
          _showFeedback('error', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> ' + response, $addToCartForm);
          $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
          _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addToCartBtnLabel);
        }
      }
    });   
    return false;    
  });
});
  };
   return {
    init: function(params) {
    // Configuration
    params = params || {};
    // Merging with defaults.
    $.extend(_config, params);
    // Action
    $(function() {
      _init();
    });
},    
getConfig: function() {
  return _config;
}
  }  
})(jQuery);

Shopify.AjaxifyCart.init();
```

Comment: Can you show which data in **cart** on ajax success?

Comment: Hi Kison, being very confused by this sort of stuff so please forgive me! Does that mean can I output what's in the cart on ajax success using the Ajax script? I can post the whole script if it might help, but wan't sure if I'd be posting a load of irrelevant code?

Comment: "Does that mean can I output what's in the cart on ajax success using the Ajax script?" Yep, need to see cart structure in ajax response, cause i see that it has not have structure the same as on server.

Comment: But maybe i`m wrong. However if you show full structure it will encrease chances to have an answer on question.

Comment: You can simply add console.log(cart) in your success function to see structure of cart variable

Comment: Does it help if I post the URL of one of the product pages (http://essential-woodwork.myshopify.com/products/25mm-bullnose-window-sill) whereby tht "Buy" button is what then updates the cart count in the top right of the header. I'll also update my original post with the full script to hopefully give a better idea of what I'm trying to amend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, as i can see everything that you need is convert server script to js format. It will be something like this:

```
$.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL, function(cart) {
    if (_config.cartCountSelector && $(_config.cartCountSelector).size()) {
        var value = $(_config.cartCountSelector).html() || '0',
            itemsCount = 0;
        $.each(cart.items, function(key, item) {
            if (item.product_type != "mw_product_option") {       
                 itemsCount += item.quantity;
            }
        });
        $(_config.cartCountSelector).html(value.replace(/[0-9]+/, itemsCount)).removeClass('hidden-count');
    }        
    ...
});
```